# How to debug Laravel Blade file during rendering

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm working on a Laravel 7 app that is using data it gets from an API. Sometimes part of the data from the API is missing and I try to catch that firstly in the controller, secondly in the Blade view. But I still get crashes during rendering of the Blade view, that I have trouble debugging. I suspect that the crash occurs during rendering of statements like this:

```
        <div class="flex-none">
             <img src="{{ $game['coverImage'] }}" alt="cover">
        </div>
```

or like this:

```
 @foreach($game['screenshots'] as $screenshot)
    @if(isset($screenshot))
    <div>
        <a href="{{ $screenshot['huge'] }}">
            <image src="{{ $screenshot['big']}}" alt="screenshot"
                class="hover:opacity-75 transition ease-in-out duration-150"></image>
        </a>
    </div>
    @endif
    @endforeach
```

Is there a way to dump the values of the variable during  rendering of the Blade file? Equivalent to dd() or dump().

Or are there better ways to debug these crashes?

Kind regards,

Hubert

Comment: if there is an error there would be a stack trace ... but you can dump variables any time you want

Comment: try `<?php print_r($vairavle) ?>`  it will print object into view file

Comment: You can use `{{ dd($xyz) }}` or `{{ dump($xyz) }}` inside your blade files